# Can't understand backslash in C++ code comments

Tags: c++, comments, backslash

I am reading some C++ code, and I find some comments like this

```
/// This method updates the placeholders in \p ph with the tensor content                                                                                                                                                                     
/// values \p inputs, in \p bindings.

/// \returns the single Function contained in this Module.                                                                                                                                                                                  
/// \pre Must be a single Function in the Module.
```

So what's the meaning of these backslash words,"\p,\return,\pre",why use that,can anybody
explains it? Thanks very much.

Comment: They are probably used by a document generator.

Comment: Probably Doxygen directives: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html

Comment: Thank you guys, it should be Doxygen directives.